# Do I store Image assets in public or src in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react for my application. I have a `div` that I would like to have a background image. But I can't get it to show.

When I include it in the `src` folder as `myapp/src/bgimage.png` it works perfectly but I've heard that I should include it in a folder named `images` at the root level so it's `myapp/images/bgimage.png`, however this does not work for me and gives me:

> You attempted to import ../images/bgimage.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory.'

Can anyone tell me the proper way to include image assets in reactJS?

Comment: Are u using webpack or other bundler?

Comment: @RickLee I think he's using `create-react-app` that's how I encountered the same error. And it's using `webpack 2`.

Comment: You should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory) it's a similar issue to yours. I've encountered the same issue as well, what I did was just put the `assets` folder inside the `src` directory.

Answer (score 180):

public: anything that is not used by your app when it compiles

src: anything that is used when the app is compiled

So for example if you use an image inside a component, it should be in the src folder but if you have an image outside the app (i.e. favicon) it should be in public.

Comment: what does it mean by "not used by your app"?

Comment: @Fadhil guess it means not of actual usage in any React component or in stylesheets

Comment: @Fadhil not required for the app to compile

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say that a favicon is "outside the app", although I can understand what you mean by that. Is there any other example besides the favicon that should be in public? Could you explain why?

Answer (score 56):

I would add that creating an "assets" folder inside the "src" folder is a good practice.

Answer (score 32):

### Use `/src` if you are using `create-react-app`

---

If you are using `create-react-app`, You need to use `/src` for the [following benefits](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder).

> 1. Scripts and stylesheets get minified and bundled together to avoid extra network requests.
> 2. Missing files cause compilation errors instead of 404 errors for your users.
> 3. Result filenames include content hashes so you don’t need to worry about browsers caching their old versions.

Also, if you are using **webpack's asset bundling** anyway, then your files in `/src` will be rebuilt.

> You may create subdirectories inside src. For faster rebuilds, only files inside src are processed by webpack. You need to put any JS and CSS files inside src, otherwise webpack won’t see them.

See this [link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure/)

Comment: What if the ReactJc project houses 20.000 images? And also users can download images!

Comment: I think storing 20,000 into project is not good idea. Use remote storage and download and use it

Comment: I know about remote storage the question is how to do it in one of the assets-in-public-or-src

Answer (score 13):

No,

public folder is for static file like index.html and ...

I think you should make an "assets" folder in src folder
and access them in this way.

Comment: Why would you say an image is not static?

Comment: This answer makes no sense whatsoever, I don't get how it has 15 upvotes...

Answer (score 10):

In this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/react-best-practices-804def6d5215), I mentioned that

> Keep an assets folder that contains top-level CSS, images, and font files.

In react best practices we keep an assets folder inside the src which may contain top-level CSS, images, and font files.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#when-to-use-the-public-folder) documentation, regarding the use of the public folder:

> Normally we recommend importing stylesheets, images, and fonts from JavaScript. The public folder is useful as a workaround for a number of less common cases:
>
> - You need a file with a specific name in the build output, such as manifest.webmanifest.
> - You have thousands of images and need to dynamically reference their paths.
> - You want to include a small script like pace.js outside of the bundled code.
> - Some libraries may be incompatible with webpack and you have no other option but to include it as a  tag.

Answer (score 6):

In continuation with the other answers I would further like to add that you should create an 'assets' folder under 'src' folder and then create 'images' folder under 'assets' folder. You can store your images in the 'images' folder and then access them from there.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding I will go with easier way. If you use your assets from public folder, after build contents from public will be maintained as same. So, if you deploy your app, the contents from public folder will also be loaded while your app loads. Assume your build is 5 MB (4 MB assets and 1 MB src) the 4 MB will get downloaded first then follows the src contains. Even if you use lazy and suspense your app will be slow during deployment.