# React App storing images in public folder vs require them from src folder

Tags: reactjs, image, src, public-folders

React app, Is there any difference (performance, lifecycle or any other aspects I can't think about) between storing images in public folder and display them by using:

```
<img src="/image.jpg" />
```

or storing images in src folder and use them with:

```
<img src={require('../../assets/image.jpg')} />
```

Comment: You have a few perks by resolving the image by using require. Look at this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/images

Comment: is it valid also for reactjs, or only for react native ?

Comment: Only for react native, sorry! Didn't notice the reactjs tag. In reactjs, the only difference is how the image is resolved. If you use require the image will be resolved automatically when built, but it will be always an URL.

Comment: These points should be applicable to both reactjs and react-native: 1. Only the images that are actually used will be packaged into your app. 2. Images live in the same folder as your JavaScript code. Components are self-contained. 3. No global namespace, i.e. you don't have to worry about name collisions. 4. Images can be distributed via npm packages. - From the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images) @AngelGonzález provided.

Comment: [Do I store Image assets in public or src in reactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44643041/2873538)