# Updating to create-react-app v4 , not rendering images

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I just updated to `create-react-app` v4

So my updated dependencies looks as follows

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.0",
```

I have deleted all my `node_modules` folder and reinstalled them again

I have included all my images in an images folder which is present in `src` folder of `create-react-app`. When i go back to  `react-scripts  3.4.4`, my images are rendering properly but in `v4.0.0` images are not rendered at all. I am using both `png` and `svg` in my app and both fail to render.

**Edit:**
I have found that images in public folder seems to render without any issue. But i want the images used by my components in src folder which are still not rendering and placing images used by components in src folder is a good practice. [Do I store Image assets in public or src in reactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643041/do-i-store-image-assets-in-public-or-src-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try updating require to import statement.

```js
const myImg = require('../imagepath.jpg')
```

to

```js
import myImg from '../imagepath.jpg'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is require deprecated in create-react-app v4?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `NODE_PATH`?

There is a breaking change in [v4.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v4.0.0).

> **Removed typescript flag and NODE_PATH support**
>
> We've removed the deprecated typescript flag when creating a new app.
> Use --template typescript instead. We've also dropped deprecated
> NODE_PATH flag as this has been replaced by setting the base path in
> jsconfig.json.

If you are using it, use `jsconfig.json` instead.

Comment: I am not using NODE_PATH and not using Typescript. I am using JS

Answer (score 0):

Shyam's answer works when your image URL is static, however, if you want the URL to be created dynamically it won't work.

If that's the case you can use this [answer](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9992#issuecomment-787922666) from GitHub:

> require("../../assets/images/others/"+loginBgImage)
>
> loginBgImage can have different values (login-image.jpg,
> login-new-image.jpg)
>
> this got fixed using
> require("../../assets/images/others/"+loginBgImage).default

The .default after the require does the trick.