# Set image src with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting an error when I try to set the `src` of an image using `props`.

I searched a lot for a solution to this problem, but all of them, brings me to the `require()`, and then set the `props` inside it. But, it's not working to me.

The image path it's correct, because when I use the `import` method to set the `src` of an image, it works. But I need lots of "`ProjectCard()`" components, and the `props` solution is better.

Component that contains the image:

```
import React from 'react';

const ProjectCard = (props) => (
    <div>
        <img src={ require(props.image).default } />
    </div>
);

export default ProjectCard;
```

Component that it's importing the ProjectCard():

```
import React from 'react';    
import ProjectCard from './components/ProjectCard/';

const App = () => (
    <ProjectCard image="../../images/image.jpg" />
);

export default App;
```

I've tried this solution too, but didn't go well (using single quotes):

```
<ProjectCard image="'../../images/image.jpg'" />
```

Both tentatives, I get the same error:

> Error: Cannot find module '../../assets/image.jpg'

I used create-react-app.

Comment: It's probably because you're using relative paths, and the component that you're passing to isn't in the same hierarchy (it's too shallow or too deep). Use absolute paths to alleviate that. ;)

Comment: Ok! I'm gonna try to use absolute path, and then I'll give the feedback!

Comment: You can import that image into parent component, in your case App like this
import Diamond from '../../images/image.jpg'; and use it <ProjectCard image={Diamond} />

Comment: Yeah, with this, works fine. But, how I said, I need lots of "ProjectCard()" components, and the props solution is better.

Comment: @mohitjain is correct. Import the images and pass them as a prop to `ProjectCard` component. The alternative is to move the images into the `public` folder and then specify the paths from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### PUBLIC FOLDER

Considering you have a public folder structured as followed,

```
- public
   |- images
       |- image.jpg
```

You can structure your components as such:

```js
const App = () => (
    <ProjectCard image="image.jpg" />
);
```

```js
const ProjectCard = (props) => (
    <div>
        <img src={`images/${props.image}`} />
    </div>
);
```

Where your image path will simply be absolute to the public folder, as `images/image.jpg`

---

### SRC FOLDER

On the other hand, if you have your images inside your src folder as followed,

```
- src
   |- components
       |- ProjectCard.jsx
   |- images
       |- image.jpg
   App.jsx
```

You can structure your components as such:

```js
import image from "./images/image.jpg";

const App = () => (
    <ProjectCard image={image} />
);
```

```js
const ProjectCard = (props) => (
    <div>
        <img src={props.image} />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: I tried to pass all images to the PUBLIC FOLDER, but it brings me another error, but this time, in my `style.css` which is: `Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported`. Because I'm trying to set a `background-image`.

Comment: And about the images in the SRC FOLDER, importing all of them. I have lots of images, and I don't think that importing all of them is a "good practice". Or it is?

Comment: Regarding your first question, if you see above you can notice I used absolute path, not relative - Regarding your second, when you create new `create-react-app` projects, you can find the spinning logo to be on the src, so it's defo not a bad practice to have them there - Read more about the difference between storing images in public vs src here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45300180/11895568

Comment: Ok, so I'm gonna import the images to use as a prop. Thank you so much! :D