When to use public vs assets for images and files in a Vite project?
I'm working on a Vite project and I struggle to understand the difference between each folder and when to use them for each of my assets.
From Vite Docs about public:

If you have assets that are:

Never referenced in source code (e.g. robots.txt)
Must retain the exact same file name (without hashing)
...or you simply don't want to have to import an asset first just to get its URL

Then you can place the asset in a special public directory under your project root.

And about assets:

Referenced assets are included as part of the build assets graph, will get hashed file names, and can be processed by plugins for optimization.

So, if I have an SVG icon that I reference in my source code, it seems it shouldn’t be in  public, since I'm referencing it in the source code.
However, in the official React + Vite example they use icons from both folders:

In App.tsx:
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg';
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

And in index.html, the icon from the public folder is referenced again:
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />

Given this, is there a practical difference between using public and assets for this case?
What are the best practices for each?

I have the same question. Found some relevant info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643041/do-i-store-image-assets-in-public-or-src-in-reactjs
