# Cannot get the styles of @ant-design/pro-layout to work with `create-react-app`

Tags: create-react-app, ant-design-pro

I am trying to use [`@ant-design/pro-layout`](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro-layout) in a `create-react-app` `typescript` project.

I cannot get the styles of `@ant-design/pro-layout` to work. The components load well, but the LESS does not.

Is there anything to do in particular other than following the tutorial [use with `create-react-app`](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app)?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
From what i understood as I am a newbie in React, create-react-app **does not** compile less although it does so for sass and scss.

So you have 2( +1) options as stated in [antd documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app).

1. Install [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) package to handle .less files as in [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Advanced-Guides) **OR**
2. Eject. (An answer to what is `eject` is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308936/what-does-this-react-scripts-eject-command-do)). After injecting you can choose [less-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/less-loader/) and modify webpack.config.js. In webpack.config.js you must add:

```js
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  use: [
    { loader: "style-loader" },
    { loader: "css-loader" },
    {
      loader: "less-loader",
      options: {
        lessOptions: {
          javascriptEnabled: true,
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

**dont forget** the `javascriptEnabled: true`.

3. I found [another way without ejecting](https://blog.bitsrc.io/using-less-with-create-react-app-without-ejecting-510a3344ef5d) ( i haven't tested it ).

Personally i ejected and configured manually webpack.