# Webpack + React - Can't resolve 'react' in submodule

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to use `webpack` to serve a smaller bundle of my react applications. I have two parts (`client` and `admin`), but I only have concerns with regards to the `client` part.

I have tried the following:

- Created the `webpack.config.js` file in the root

  ```
  module.exports = {
      module: {
          rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    babelrc: false,
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'],
                },
           },
           {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
           },
           {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader',
                ],
           },
           {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
           },
           {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                 {
                   loader: 'file-loader',
                 },
                ],
           },
         ],
     },
  };
  ```
- I have added the `options` to ignore babel because I could not make it import the `.babelrc` file and it kept throwing:

> `Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled`.

However, every time I run webpack, it throws errors such as:

> `ERROR in ./node_modules/react-side-effect/lib/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in 'project_path\node_modules\react-side-effect\lib'`
>
> `ERROR in ./client/src/App.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in 'project_path'`
>
> `ERROR in ./client/src/components/resources/PDFCard.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in 'project_path'`

Did I mistype a **test**?

**EDIT**

Here is the babel file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "version": "1.6.1",
  "description": "app_description",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development ./client/src/index.js --output ./client/public/bundle.js",
    "start": "node server",
    "server": "nodemon server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "admin": "npm start --prefix admin",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\" \"npm run admin\""
  },
  "author": "David - Marian Buzatu",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "apexcharts": "^3.19.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.671.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.12",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.7",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-minimal-pie-chart": "^6.0.1",
    "react-pdf": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.1",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

Also, I am running the `npm run build` script from the root folder. `client`, where the react project resides, is inside this root folder.

Comment: Are those modules installed?

Comment: Yes, they are. Running the website even in production without problems. The problem occurs with webpack only

Comment: can u show package.json

Comment: I have updated my question with the `package.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was that the project was built using the `npx create-react-app` command. That one comes with some `react-scripts` that generate their own webpack and take care of bundling.

Comment: So, what's the workaround if we want to use webpack manually?

Comment: I think you need to look over this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308936/what-does-this-react-scripts-eject-command-do). You have to use `react-scripts eject` in order to get out the webpack config and add your options to that.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I only needed to install `react`, `react-native` and `react-dom` as devDependencies, even though they are already there inside peerDependencies. IMO this is so that Webpack can actually understand where `import React from 'react';` comes from (the node_modules).