# Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it) React-Intl for translation

Tags: react-intl

Facing Below build issue:

```
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
```

Any please provide some solution for this ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I got this error when exporting a module with async.
Just add this to the module.exports object in webpack.config.js file.

```js
experiments: {
  topLevelAwait: true
}
```

You can also read up about the experiment option in Webpack documentation. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/

Comment: But where's the webpack.config.js file? Mine didn't come with one. Do I need to create one myself?

Comment: @HaiNaZheng yes you need to create one. 

You can do this by creating a new file called webpack.config.js

I found the first half of this video helpful - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IG4UmULyoA

Comment: @Bello Tomi To make this work, do we need to install craco package?

Comment: yes @ShouryaShikhar

Comment: `experiments:` was introduced in Webpack 5

Comment: HOw to enabee top level await in gatsby.js ?

Answer (score 18):

Here's a workaround for those coming from Next.js [source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43382#issuecomment-1328978266)

```
/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  experimental: { appDir: true },
  webpack(config) {
    config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true }
    return config
  },
}
```

Comment: A question though, what does this do and what side effects does it have?

Comment: a module can include an await in the code that executes at startup by factoring that code into an async function.

Answer (score 6):

You can enable it in your webpack config.

If you created your react app with `npx create-react-app my-app` you have to install [CRACO](https://github.com/dilanx/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#installation) to override your webpack config.

After installation set topLevelAwait to true in your craco.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      experiments: {
        topLevelAwait: true,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Run `npm start` and the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

**Symfony**

For anyone else trying to add this to the webpack.config.js generated by symfony, you can use the following syntax:

```js
// Default config above...

const config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

config.experiments = {
  topLevelAwait: true,
}

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Starting from webpack version 5.83.0, this feature [experiments.topLevelAwait] is enabled by
> default.
> (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/#experimentstoplevelawait)

So as alternative to the experiments option, you can upgrade webpack.
I had to eject my react app to upgrade. ([What does this "react-scripts eject" command do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308936/what-does-this-react-scripts-eject-command-do))