# Next.js and reusable API calls

Tags: javascript, next.js

In my Next.js blog app, I am getting content by using an external API call. I am using the same two calls over several pages (post, categories, tags, authors etc.). Instead of repeating these calls I have been trying to create two main global calls like this

```
import { getAuthors } from "@/libs/getAuthors";
import { getPosts } from "@/libs/getPosts"; 

export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      posts: getPosts(),
      authors: getAuthors(),
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```

I also had to add the following to my next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["images.ctfassets.net"],
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.experiments = { topLevelAwait: true, layers: true };
    return config;
  },
};
```

as partially described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474803/error-the-top-level-await-experiment-is-not-enabled-set-experiments-toplevelaw) answer. This works, but slows down the page quite a lot, why is this happening? What's the correct way to create and use such global API calls?

**UPDATE:**

```
import { createClient } from "contentful";

const client = createClient({
  space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY,
});

const auth_data = await client.getEntries({ content_type: "author" });

export function getAuthors() {
  var authors = [];

  var auth_len = auth_data.items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < auth_len; i++) {
    authors.push({
      authorSlug: auth_data.items[i].fields.name
        .toString()
        .replace(/ /g, "-")
        .toLowerCase(),
      authorContent: auth_data.items[i].fields.description,
      authorFrontMatter: {
        title: auth_data.items[i].fields.name,
        image: "https:" + auth_data.items[i].fields.image.fields.file.url,
      },
    });
  }
  return authors;
}
```

Comment: Why have you enabled `topLevelAwait` if you're not calling `await` at the top level (at least not in the code you've shared)?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by _"but slows down the page quite a lot"_? How is the page slow?

Comment: @juliomalves in `getPosts()` and `getAuthors()` I am calling `await`. The loading time on the web pages goes up by several seconds when implementing `topLevelAwait`

Comment: Could it be that all instances of `getPosts()` and `getAuthors()` are running at first load?

Comment: Please show all the relevant code.