# Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled in Next.js with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

## **I'm new to Next.js and Firebase**

I'm trying to query data from firestore in my Next.js project using node v16.15.0 and next@13.2.1.

I'm following this documentation :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=en#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

But when i'm trying to query data, i have this error :

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCeAO.png)

And this is my `next.config.js` file :

```
 /**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
 const nextConfig = {
   reactStrictMode: true,
   images: {
     domains: ['lh3.googleusercontent.com']
 },
 experiments: {
   topLevelAwait: true
 }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

So I tried to query data following the docs, and this is my code :

```
import { app } from "../firebaseConfig";
import {
  getFirestore,
  doc,
  getDocs,
  collection,
} from "firebase/firestore/lite";

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "cities"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});

const ProfilePage = (cours) => {
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  if (user !== null) {
    const displayName = user.displayName;
    const email = user.email;
    const photoURL = user.photoURL;
    const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    const uid = user.uid;
  }

  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  if (!currentUser) {
    router.push("/loginPage");
  }

  return (
    // my code
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

And when i run it on localhost i have the error :
`error - ./pages/profilePage.js Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it) Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)`

So how can I get rid of this error ? Where should I put the await?
Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried to set `experiments.topLevelAwait: true`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it) React-Intl for translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474803/error-the-top-level-await-experiment-is-not-enabled-set-experiments-toplevelaw)