# React path to public folder in css background image

Tags: html, css, json, reactjs

I am using Create-React-App and I want to add background image for my header section and I am doing this in that way:

```
background-image: url('~/Screenshot_11.png');
```

After this I'm getting this error:

> ./src/styles/main.scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/styles/main.scss)
> Module not found: You attempted to import
> ../../../../../../../Screenshot_11.png which falls outside of the
> project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not
> supported.

I've set up homepage in package.json

```
"homepage": "http://localhost:3000",
```

In my older projects that works but today I cannot import this correctly.

Comment: `~` usually points to the default location on your os ( I think). Have you tried this:
`background-image: url('./Screenshot_11.png');`

Comment: Not working too

Answer (score 32, accepted):

They have changed that but I don't know why. Working path:

```
background-image: url('/Screenshot_11.png');
```

**EDIT 2021**

For people who think that it doesn't work:

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-turing-gsnr3

Comment: This still does not work for me with images in the public folder.

Comment: You need to look inside your Network tab in Developer tools and see what path are you requesting maybe that will help you

Comment: For those like me struggling to make their CSS in SRC folder to work with their images in the PUBLIC folder, see the explanation behind the recommendation to move the images to SRC folder here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1248#issuecomment-266313612 As explained in the link, " You shouldn't need images in public; the build process will copy images from src/ to build/ at compile time (and update paths accordingly). "

Comment: @JamesHubert please send us an example when this is not working

Answer (score 17):

you can import that image as

```
import Background from './Screenshot_11.png'
```

and use

```
background-image: `url(${Background})`
```

Comment: Helped me with react-scripts v4 and styled-components. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

> This still does not work for me with images in the public folder.

**UPDATED 19 March 2021**

Regarding using of <ROOT/public/images> in .css files.

It appears to be a breaking change (will be considered as a bug?) in create-react-app (react-scripts) package v4.x.
And more precisely in package 'css-loader' v4.x.
3.x branch works OK with that.

Here is the corresponding issue on the github repo:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9870
(and there are few more actually).

No fixes (yet). (will be?..)
But a few workarounds mentioned there.
Which one to use... it depends on your project, I suppose.

Some of workarounds:

- downgrade to react-scripts 3.4.x
- don't use url in CSS files :) you still can use in .JSX (inline styles). Or put in .html. They are obviously not processed by css-loader.
- reconfigure webpack to add url:false to css-loader options (either eject CRA or use this: https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco or this: https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired
  (you can find sample configurations at the github issue page)
- use this new feature of css-loader https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/pull/1264
  (released in 5.1.0, current last version is 5.1.3; to use that version you can add the following to the package.json: "resolutions": { "css-loader": "5.1.3" } (at root level) )

Comment: Short answer - move the image to the src/images folder instead of it being in Public.