# How to import images from public folder in react in App.css

Tags: css, reactjs

**The error**
[image: 1]

I am facing an issue to import images from the public folder in App.css under background image attribute.

```css
.sign-up {
    background-image: url('/images/img-8.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100px;
  }
```

React version used: react@17.0.2

**Public folder structure**

[image: 2]

**Folder structure**

[image: 3]
The aforementioned is the image of the error that is shown, It would be helpful to receive a solution to this

Comment: Did you take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111197/react-path-to-public-folder-in-css-background-image

Comment: @LahEzcen, yes I checked as( background-image: url('/images/img-8.jpg'); )  but it isn't working as (

Comment: I put my `images` folder in my `src` folder.

Comment: @Azu maybe I'll do that at last if I don't find any way for this one, thanks for the advice though

Answer (score -1):

there is no `img-8.jpg` in your public folder please check the name again

Comment: This not an answer to the OP. Please leave a comment instead of this type of the answers.