# Create React App 4.0 cannot resolve image path in public folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have upgraded to the latest Create React App 4.0. Now the `scss` cannot resolve image assets in the public folder. I was using CRA 3.4.1 before. It worked fine.

Any ideas? I don't want to use `npm eject`

The icon.svg is in `public/images`

`background-image: url(/images/icon.svg);`

```
Failed to compile.

./src/Components/style.scss 
(./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!
./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!
./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!
./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!
./src/Components/style.scss)
Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../../icon.svg' in ''
```

In Create React App 3.x, referencing an image from the [public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) in (S)CSS worked by simply using a starting slash, as has been been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54737158/401712).

As the OP has explained, the image is in `public/images` and is being referenced as `url(/images/icon.svg)`.

This doesn't work in Create React App 4.0.0 anymore and gives the error message `Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../../icon.svg' in ''`. The [changelog of Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) doesn't mention a breaking change regarding the public folder.

Comment: Here is a issue on CRA repo for this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10022

Answer (score 1):

I think it is deprecated in `CRA 4`, (after all.. it was a breaking change..)
there are some workarounds using `craco` but I suggest to move these files to the `src` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change to this: (webpack should resolve this to the 'real' path)

```
background-image: url(./icon.svg);
```

I know you wanted to add the image as a **background-image** css property, but maybe another approach is relevant for you.

When you import like this you use it exactly as you would use a normal Component:

```
import { ReactComponent as Icon } from'<path_to_resource>/images/icon.svg';

<Icon />
```

Source:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Answer (score -2):

As a temporary workaround, you could move the images into `src/`, import them directly in the components `import myImage from '../file.svg'` and set `style={{ backgroundImage: file }}>`?

Comment: importing it in the src directory would include them in the production build