# I was adding a background image in my react js . But it is showing an error

Tags: css, reactjs

I have seen on the internet they were telling to add image in the public folder . So i added my image  into the public folder by creating a sub folder name img in which i place my image "mario.png" in it.

As i wanted to add that image as the  background image so i wrote this code in my index.css

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: url(/img/mario.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-color: #95e8f3;  
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

and still it was not working it was showing the error :
**
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: Can't resolve '/img/mario.png' in 'D:\Users\PIRATES\Desktop\cool\src'
**

[image: This is the folder structure]

But when i created a asset folder in src then it was working but i want to know why it is not working when i am placing my image in the public folder.

Comment: url value should be in quotes url('/img/mario.png')

Comment: @PunithMithra i have added the double quotes even it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162841/use-images-in-css-files-with-reactjs?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64852112/create-react-app-4-0-cannot-resolve-image-path-in-public-folder

Comment: @fast-reflexes Yes this is working . But everyone was telling that you should add the image in the public folder and the react automatically detects it is in public folder so this was not working  and i just want to know why ?

Comment: For me, it works to put it in the public folder. If you use it like `<img src="/img/mario.png" />` does it work then?

Comment: @fast-reflexes yes it works for me.  If i am adding the img tag.  Thanks for the link of the above post.

Comment: So then it seems to be something special with this css processing (the postcss-loader). As I said it works for me even when used as a background in css (but I don't know if I use this postcss-loader) but I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Now at least you know that you can use the public folder for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `url` function properly. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url())

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: url("/img/mario.png");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-color: #95e8f3;  
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the relative path inside the `url` function, not the absolute path from the root of the project.

Considering your screenshot, you have to write something like this:

```css
background: url('../public/img/mario.png');
```