# How to add Pseudo element selector before content url in react.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to add image inside the Pseudo element selector 'before' on content property using 'url()', in HTML and CSS it is working fine but when I added the HTML inside react(JSX) and attached the CSS file, I am getting error as below

```
    Failed to compile
    
    ./src/style.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/style.css)
    Module not found: Can't resolve './ascending-sort.png' in 'D:\JAVA\Prog\My Projects\Sort Visualizer\sort-visualizer\src'
```

CSS code

```
.navbar__header::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: url("ascending-sort.png");
    left: -40px;
    top: -5px;
}
```

JSX

```
 <div className="navbar__header">Sort Visualizer</div>
```

Is there any different way to deal with Pseudo element selectors in react.

Comment: The error seems to tell you it cannot find the `ascending-sort.png` file... I guess it is somewhere like in `/public`. So just check the path to the image.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have checked the path it is correct, i.e. the image `ascending-sort.png` is present inside the public folder, is there any way to provide path because I tried using this  `./public/ascending-sort.png`  but got same error.

Comment: I am not sure if the path in the `url()` should be from the root of your app or from the file it tries to compile... So possibilities are `/public/ascending-sort.png` or `../public/ascending-sort.png`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I tried both of them but didn't work.

Comment: I found a similar question [Reference file in public folder from CSS in create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841775/reference-file-in-public-folder-from-css-in-create-react-app) So seems you just need a `/` in front of the filename... Did you try that?