# Adding path to an image in CSS module from public folder in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I am trying to add an image as background, however the location of image is in a pulic folder.
-public
-images
-image.png
-src
-assets
-components
-index.tsx
-index.module.css  (I want to use the image.png in this file)

If I put the image in `src/assets`, I can use it as `background: url(./assets/image.png)`. I can also access it in `index.tsx`. However, I am trying to access the image in `module.css` from the public folder as I need to change the image on hover.

```
.up {
  /*path in source works*/
  background: url(../../../../assets/keyboardKeys/keyboardArrows.png) 150px 51px;   

  /*path outside source. inside public. I want to use this */
  background: url(Assets/keyboardKeys/keyboardArrows.png) 150px 51px; 
}
```

Using the second url results in the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/app/index.module.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/app/index.module.css)
```

Comment: You have not stated what problem you are having, also there is no code. Can you provide details on the error/issue? And give a sample of relevant code?

Comment: All the files in the public folder should be accessible ... publicly. As in - statically served. You can double check if the file is returned on the url that you expect by going to it directly. This would be something like `localhost:<yourport>/Assets/keyboardKeys/keyboardArrows.png`. If that is not returning your image, there's your problem.

Comment: Also, probably add a `/` at the start of paths as well as quoting it. `background: url('/Assets/keyboardKeys/keyboardArrows.png')`

Comment: @Phil The thing is I don't want to add it statically because if the port is busy, it would result in an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841775/reference-file-in-public-folder-from-css-in-create-react-app

Comment: Well yes, if you don't want to host your asset statically, do not add it to the public folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use file inside public folder directly

```
background: url(folderInPublic/image.png)
```

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work. Attached the code now in my question