# ReactJS import component outside src/ directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have two react apps(A-app, B-app). I need to import one component from A-app to B-app.
But when I tried to do this I have seen this error.

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../src/components/Dashboard/container which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

I tried to do symlink on this component in B-app node_modules. But it didn`t work.

Also I tried to create .env file in root project directory and put this `NODE_PATH=src/`
in file. But this solve doesn`t work too.

How can I fix this?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Why creating a symlink didn't work? What error did you get?

Comment: If I created symlink, I see `Module not found: You attempted to import ../../src/components/Dashboard/container which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/`. I think it`s because I haven`t .min in my component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got to your A-app `node_modules` folder and run the following

```
ln -s ../../../src/components/Dashboard ./app-b-dashboard
```

After creating the following symbolic link in your `node_modules` folder you can `import` in you A-app

```
import Dashboard from 'app-b-dashboard/container'
```

The names might be different depending on the specific layout of your project. This is my best guess based on the info you provided.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! How to do symlink from B-app on all modules in directory node_modules A-app?

Comment: I think it would be better to ask a new question by stackexchange rules. Anyway if all you need in B-app is just A-app modules maybe you could just replace the `node_modules` of B-app with symlink to A-app `node_modules`. But i really not sure it is a good idea. Another option create symlinks one by one

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much for answer!

Answer (score 25):

I stumbled on this post while trying to solve a similar issue. I think the solution might be relevant so I'm posting it here.

As of NPM 2.0 you can declare local dependencies in `package.json`. This allows you to maintain local modules in a folder outside of `src/` and have them copied to `node_modules` during `npm install`.

Place your module anywhere outside of `src/`, for example:

```
./packages/app-b-dashboard
```

Declare a local dependency in `package.json` using the `file:` prefix:

```
"dependencies": {
  "app-b-dashboard": "file:./packages/app-b-dashboard"
}
```

Run

```
npm install
```

Now you can import it in your A-app

```
import Dashboard from 'app-b-dashboard/container'
```

Comment: Is this solution still valid, can anybody confirm? because when try this I am getting another error.  -> Could not install from "..\my\component\path\from\AppB" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but it gives me this exception`Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.` but I do have this the @babel/preset-react in the presets, how can I fix it?

Comment: @RavikumarB it does work, and you need a package.json file in the folder you're importing from.

Answer (score 8):

are you using create react app ? if yes, you need to move your module into your src directory.
This is special restriction added by developers of create-react-app .
mentioned  [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1699)

If moving the code is not an option for you, there are 2 solutions.

- make the component as a module and npm install it like a private
  package
- There is a workaround  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

Comment: Yes, I use create-react-app. I can to move component in src/ directory, but I don`t want to copy the code. It`s reason why I try to import from outside of src/.

Comment: why the downvote?   both the soutions provided do solve  op's  requirement

Answer (score 0):

I removed my `node_module` and `package-lock.json` files. and reinstall `npm` using `npm install` resolved my errors. I dont know this is a good way to do it. but its worked for me.