# React - Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Tags: reactjs

I am using React, and am trying to access a resource that is not in the `src` directory, this results in an error.

**Question**

Is it possible to access a `.js` (i.e. `index.js`) file that is outside the `src` directory?

I have the following directory structure:

```
- client
     - src
          - App.js
- data
     - index.js
```

**index.js**

```
const ShiftList = [
   {... data ...}
]

module.exports = { ShiftList }
```

**App.js**

```
import { ShiftList } from '../../data/index.js';
```

I get the following error:

> ./src/App.js Module not found: You attempted to import
>   ../../data/index which falls outside of the project src/ directory.
>   Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: Did you create the project using create-react-app? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

Comment: @krmckone, thanks for the reply.  No I did not. It is something I have inherited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS import component outside src/ directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705170/reactjs-import-component-outside-src-directory)

Answer (score 2):

For this you might do the following in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "app-b-dashboard": "file:./data/index"
}
```

and then you should be able to import as

```
import Dashboard from 'app-b-dashboard/container'
```

Comment: @r_bara, thank you, but what is `Dashboard`?  I need to get `ShiftList`.

Comment: I have a `package.json` in the `root` and `client` directory. Which one must I apply this to?

Comment: yes, you need to import Index in the package.json(root directory)

Comment: `npm install` gives `npm ERR! Could not install from "data/index" as it does not contain a package.json file.`.

Comment: This answer looks like a copy of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56849993/4336873.

Comment: Does that work for Windows?