# how to automate reactjs build process using batch file?

Tags: javascript, windows, reactjs, batch-file, cmd

I want to automate reactjs build process. So I created batch file contains series of commands like

```
cd react-project && npm i && npm run eject && npm run build && serve -s build
```

Everything works fine until it executes `serve -s build` it is supposed to keep running the command without closing `cmd` but it shutdown `cmd` without throwing an error

Comment: The `eject` command must be run only once at project life. And [most probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory) you do not need to run it.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of that but in my case development code is not ejected. I copy that code in deployment and follow the same process again. That why I want to make the batch file and its execution should do my job

Comment: What is `serve`? it's not a native Windows `cmd` command...

Comment: not serve is node enviroment command

Answer (score 1):

```
call npm i
call npm run build
call serve -s build -l 4000
cmd /k
```