# How to import file from public folder in react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a javascript file in the public folder and I want to import that file to components in the folder src/components.

```
projectFolder
  publicFolder
    index.html
    recorder.js
  srcFolder
    componentsFolder
       Speech.js
       Speech.css
```

But I can't do something like this in my component:

```
import Recorder from '../../public/recorder'
```

Because I get the following error:

> Module not found: You attempted to import ../../public/recorder which
>   falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside
>   of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add
>   a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

As I've understood it's not allowed to import outside of /src directory, so I was wondering how I could "add a symlink" or if you know other ways to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using create-react-app ... this is a feature included in the `ModuleScopePlugin`, and you can disable it by ejecting the app and editing your webpack configuration (as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory#answer-44115058)).

But beware, the feature exists for a reason. The create-react-app build tool only processes the src/ directory, so for example your JavaScript outside of here will not be transpiled by Babel. Furthermore, you're typically trying to avoid polluting the global scope if you're using a bundler like Webpack. So unless you've got a really specific reason why you'd need to do this, I'd say try and move it.

Comment: I've moved the file js into src/ folder but now I'm getting the following errors:

Comment: ./src/recorder.js
  Line 4:    'define' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 5:    'define' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 12:   Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 13:   Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 455:  Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 455:  Unexpected use of 'self'  no-restricted-globals

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: and also the following lines:

Comment: index.js:2178 ./src/components/Speech.js
Module not found: You attempted to import /recorder which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

Comment: Have you done anything to try and fix them? Sounds like the first one at least is pretty self-explanatory. The recorder.js file is causing your linter to fail.

Comment: I've deleted the imports from Speech.js, the component where I want to import the recorder.js file and I've deleted the recorder.js script from index.html

Comment: https://github.com/w-okada/image-analyze-workers/blob/master/tfl001_google-meet-segmentation/public/index.html 
→ The virtual background logic calls the js file in the public folder. 
They import js files from public folder in the same way as "declare function createTFLiteModule(): Promise<TFLite>;" 
But in JavaScript, that syntax doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to import it if it's not typescript?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `react-scripts` config with the [rescripts library](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts)

Create a file called `.rescriptsrc.js` in your root folder:

```
module.exports = config => {
  const scopePluginIndex = config.resolve.plugins.findIndex(
    ({ constructor }) => constructor && constructor.name === "ModuleScopePlugin"
  );

  config.resolve.plugins.splice(scopePluginIndex, 1);

  return config;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok not using the actual file in `public` and having a duplicate js file in the `src` directory there's a hacky but cool solution if you use vscode. This vscode extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emeraldwalk.RunOnSave allows you to trigger a command on save (you can use regex to specify which file saves should trigger which commands) and you can specify a command to run on save as such:

```
{
    "match": "public\\\\recorder.js$",
    "cmd": "copy ${file} ${workspaceFolder}\\src\\recorder.js"
}
```

Now you can import from that duplicated file.

Answer (score -4):

As i can see you want to import parent component in child component.

While defining path './' represents the current directory in which you are working so you can go one level up by following '../' for one level up and the same goes for the upper level directory.

So if you want to import from public folder inside Speech.js component you could do something like this.

// In Speech.js

```
import Recorder from './../../public/recorder';
```

Hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: `code`
[Failed to compile.

./src/components/Speech.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ./../../public/recorder which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.                                                                                                   
`code`

Comment: Do you have any other idea about I could do it?