# Why am I getting error "Failed to compile: Module not found: Can't resolve './components/MyInfo'" in 'c:\xampp\htdocs\reactjs\src'

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem on compiling a react app. The module was not found and the error was.

`Module not found: Can't resolve './components/MyInfo' in 'c:\xampp\htdocs\reactjs\src'`

Here is the file structure of the project.

```
reactjs
 |- git
 |   L ...
 |- components 
 |   L MyInfo.js 
 |- node_modules
 |- public 
 |   L index.html ...     
 |- src
 |    L index.js
```

Here is my file that contains JSX, filename: `index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import MyInfo from './components/MyInfo'


ReactDOM.render(
    <MyInfo />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is my file that contains the function.
path and filename: `reactjs/components/MyInfo.js`

```
import React from 'react'

function MyInfo() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>J2</h1>
            <p>I am a gamer</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Tokyo Japan</li>
                <li>Ontario Canada</li>
                <li>Beijing China</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyInfo
```

How can I locate `component/MyInfo.js`?

Thanks

Comment: You should change path import MyInfo: import MyInfo from '../components/MyInfo'

Comment: It doesnt allow to import on relative path outside src folder.
This was the error: Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import has an incorrect path based on your folder structure.

The path should be:

```
import MyInfo from './../components/MyInfo'
```

Comment: Thanks @sthotakura
The error is: Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Is there a way I can import MyInfo outside or inside src folder?

Comment: You may want to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works. Sorry for late response.