# Is there a way to import an MDX or MD markdown file in React and use it in a data array?

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I want to make a list of blog posts and therefor I thought it would be easy to use MDX because it helps with styling each blog text. But I don't know if it's possible to import a MDX file and put it in blogs.text.

I tried to use the npm package mdx.macro with it's function importMDX, but I get an error which says that the imported file is outside the src/.

mdx.macro documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdx.macro

```
import React, { lazy } from 'react';
import { importMDX } from 'mdx.macro';

const blog1 = lazy(() => importMDX('./blog1.md'));


export const blogs = [
  {
      title: "Hello World",
      subtitle: "subtitle",
      text: blog1
  }

];

export default blogs;
```

I import this file in my blog and loop through all the items. But the importMDX keeps giving me the following error:

```
Module not found: You attempted to import 
node_modules\.cache\mdx.macro\Content.6cbf05377c.mdx.js 
which falls outside of the project src/ directory. 
Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

Maybe there's an easier option than this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @mfakhrusy's answer , I had to change my blogs.js file to

```
import { mdx } from 'mdx.macro';
import Blog1 from './Blog1.js';

export const blogs = [
  {
      title: "My experiences as an intern working without getting paid",
      subtitle: "And the difficulties that come along with being undervalued by a company",
      text:  <Blog1 />
  }
];

export default blogs;
```

And my Blog1.js file contains this

```
import React from 'react';
import { mdx } from 'mdx.macro';

export const Blog1 = mdx`
# Don't Panic

Since we decided a few weeks ago to adopt the leaf as legal tender, we have, of course, all become immensely rich.
`

export default Blog1;
```

So now I can write blogs in markdown format and loop through them to show them on my website!

Answer (score 0):

According to [The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

It's a restriction from CRA developer. You can try to eject your CRA app and try it again. (see `eject` script on package json), and remove `ModuleScopePlugin` from webpack config. Be careful though, eject is a one-way trip, you cannot go back.

It happens because from what I've seen from the doc, the package tries to generate a cache file which being imported later by the app, and CRA would prohibit that by throwing that error you encountered.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I got it working, but it only works when I do this in my blogs file: `const MyDocument = mdx' #hello ' ` and then add it to my text parameter as `text : <MyDocument />`. It doesn't work when I try to import a blog from an other file, with the const MyDocument in it. Then I get a InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/static/media/Blog1.1ffec661.mdx') is not a valid name.  So something will go wrong again.

Comment: Okay the problem was that my Blog1 file was a .mdx file, but I had to change it to .js. Now it's working!