# Share JS Classes between server and client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, lerna

I'm new in Node.js and React, so please excuse me if my question is not relevant.
I have an app which uses Node.js(Express) server and React for UI. I have Classes which should be used both in server and UI. My root directory is like this

```
--root
----server
----client
----shared
```

But when I try to use the files of `shared` from `client`, I get an error `Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`
I tried to use `Lerna` for common files, but ended up with the same error.

Can anybody advise how can I solve this? Any help is appreciated.

P.S. I already tried to `eject` and remove `ModuleScopePlugin` from webpack configuration file, however that added new errors and didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

Comment: I'm curious, what do you need to do this for exactly? This kind of thing is mostly done in games for client prediction.

Comment: @JudeDesir - and also for shared validation code, for shared data structures etc. In fact, this is very common in compiled languages like C, C++, Java etc. where both server and client use the same shared libraries for data structures (in fact there are entire frameworks like CORBA and OLE that do this). It's only in web development where traditionally browser javascript has no access to shared libraries in other languages that we don't do this. Now with node we can and I've always believed we should

Comment: @JudeDesir The ability to share common concerns without wrappers, api calls, etc. is one of the selling pints of JS on the server--it's quite handy.

Comment: @JudeDesir Yes, I'm creating a game, where I need to keep users in server and also do calculations about them in UI.

Comment: in js sharing c-s code is named `isomorphic` or `universal` ... just use symlinks to make it virtually local?