# How to use react-app-rewired with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

The following StackOverflow answer told me how to use react-app-rewired to import JavaScript files from outside the `src` folder, without ejecting the app:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55298684/377011

However, when using this with a Typescript file outside of the `src` folder (i.e. `import * from '../../myfile.ts'`), I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'ts-loader' in '...\myapp'
```

So I installed `ts-loader` (`yarn add ts-loader`), but now I'm getting

```
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for ...\myapp\src\index.tsx
```

`noEmit` is set to `true` in my `tsconfig.json`.

Any idea?

**Edit:** This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: please show your tsconfig. I think you should add this file to the compilation process by adding it to the `include` or `files` property

Comment: @nickbullock See edit for tsconfig. The strange thing is that the file in the error message is a file from inside the project, i.e. inside the `src` folder. It's not an outside file.

Comment: try following steps: remove `noEmit: true` and change "include" to `"include": ["src/**/*"]`

Comment: @nickbullock Apparently, `create-react-app` instantly puts the `noEmit: true` back whenever it is removed.