# npm: import from outside the src folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

So I have this NodeJS project with the following folder tree

```
+ node-folder
   + react-app-folder
   + (other folders...)
   + config
       + default.json
```

What I am trying to do is import that `default.json` file to any file in that `react-app-folder`.

The `node-folder` and `react-app-folder` have their own `package.json` file.

Is there any way of doing this?

### Thank you all very much.

EDIT:
For more details about the `node-folder` . It is a NodeJS app server whose `package.json` has a script using `concurrently` to run both the `nodejs-app` on port 3000 and `react-app` on port 3001

Comment: are they(folders under node-folder) relative? what about treating the config fold as an individual npm package and install it to where you need.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'relative' but I've edited my question with more details, could you have a look, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I believe that you are using `create-react-app`. The `ModuleScopePlugin` enforces a restriction that prevents you from importing files outside `src` folder. Removing this from your webpack configuration will allow you to import files out of react app scope. Please check this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've read the question that you suggested. But if the React developers tried to restrict the scope of imported files in the react-app, there must be some problems or some critical principals that they want us to follow, right? I mean, wouldn't breaking the restriction crash our app in some ways or some scenarios?

Comment: I don't think doing this would crash or break anything. This rule is imposed to generate an optimised bundle once the app is built.

Answer (score -2):

i think `require` is ok, isn't it?

### commonjs

```js
// node-folder/config/default.json
exports.PORT = 8080;
```

```js
// node-folder/server/app.js
var config = require('../config/config');

console.log(config.PORT);
```

Comment: bruh, I appreciate your help and everything, but I think you've missundertood my question. My goal is to import the ```default.json``` file to any file in the ```react-app-folder```