# React js- error in import statement - Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image]

I have an action folder inside the src folder as you can see in above pic. I have component file in which I have import statements as below.

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./Login.css";
import * as LoginAction from "../../actions/loginAction";
import rp from "request-promise";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

But I am getting error as

> /src/Components/LoginComponent.js
>   Module not found: You attempted to import ../../actions/loginAction which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Can you please help to find what is wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory) can help you

Comment: @EWR it has an answer related to webpack file. In my project I dont have webpack file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `../..` you're trying to access to the parent of parent folder. That's why now you're out of the `src` folder. And this import is not currently supported.

In your code, try to modify:

```
import * as LoginAction from "../../actions/loginAction";
```

to something like one of the followings:

```
import * as LoginAction from "../actions/loginAction";
import * as LoginAction from "./action/loginAction";
import * as LoginAction from "../redux/actions/loginAction";
```