# Module not found error using Yarn 2 to link React components

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I've created a [repository](https://bitbucket.org/cjmyles/yarn2-link/src/master/) which contains a React app (created with `create-react-app`) and a components directory which contains a simple  Material UI button. The folder structure is:

```
/components
/react-app
```

Both directories are set up to use [Yarn 2](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install), and are not in a workspace (as I'm trying to simulate projects in separate directories and simplify my real world scenario).

I build the components:

```
$ cd ~/components && yarn build
```

I then [Yarn link](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/link/#examples) the components to the React app:

```
$ cd ~/react-app & yarn link ../components -r -p
```

This results in a modification to `package.json` file in the `react-app` directory:

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  ...
  "resolutions": {
    "components": "portal:../components"
  }
}
```

My `App.tsx` file looks like this:

```
import './App.css';

import { Button } from 'components';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <Button>Test</Button>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, when I run the React app using `yarn start` I get the following error:

```
./src/App.tsx
Module not found: Your application tried to access components, but it isn't declared in your dependencies; this makes the require call ambiguous and unsound.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I add an explicit reference to the components directory within `dependencies` (which I don't believe I should have to do because I've already linked it) such as:

```
"dependencies": {
  "components": "portal:../components"
}
```

Then I get the error:

```
./src/App.tsx
Module not found: You attempted to import ~/react-app/.yarn/$$virtual/components-virtual-de9a8055ab/2/components which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

Surely, I don't have to eject the app and find a way to bypass this error?

EDIT: According to the [Yarn documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/migration#enable-the-pnp-plugin-when-using-webpack-4) "Webpack 5 will support PnP natively, but if you use Webpack 4 you'll need to add the pnp-webpack-plugin plugin yourself". At the time of writing, the latest version of `create-react-app` relies on v3.4.1 of `react-scripts` which in turn relies on Webpack 4. I therefore ejected my app to inspect the Webpack configuration, and it appears that this plugin is already installed. It's therefore not a CRA/Webpack issue. I also upgraded my version of Node from v10.16.0 to v12.16.3 to no avail.

Answer (score 7):

TLDR; Add the package as a dependency then modify your React setup to import files outside of the `/src` directory.

In my case, it doesn't look like `yarn link` is doing anything other than adding a `resolutions` entry in `package.json`, which according to the [documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest#resolutions) is only used to specify the version to resolve. Perhaps my understanding of Yarn link is wrong (even though it held up in v1).

To fix the issue I had to add the reference to `dependencies` in package.json (even though I'd already run `yarn link`):

```
"dependencies": {
  "components": "portal:../components"
}
```

This caused the aforementioned `You attempted to import components which falls outside of the project src/ directory` error. To resolve this we either need to eject the React app and disable the `ModuleScopePlugin` in  Webpack (therefore allowing the import of files outside the `/src` folder), or use craco with [custom configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60353355/373406). I've created [`yarn-eject`](https://bitbucket.org/cjmyles/yarn2-link/branch/yarn-eject) and [`craco`](https://bitbucket.org/cjmyles/yarn2-link/branch/craco) branches to demonstrate both.

It's not a particularly elegant solution, and I'm hoping someone can post a better alternative. I switched to Yarn 2 so that I could utilise the ["Improved Peer Dependency Links"](https://dev.to/arcanis/introducing-yarn-2-4eh1#improved-peer-dependency-links) feature (so that I'm only relying on one version of `react` across my applications and shared components packages). I'd rather not have to eject my React app or use custom configuration if possible.

Comment: Hi Craig, I came here for the same reason as you (yarn 2 for links between react components and apps that "work" (no duplicate dependencies, no manual linking). Thanks, it works !
In this setup, what is your workflow? Do you do most of your development in the components in isolation with hot reloading ? When you want to test the component in the app, what kind of commands do you have to run after each modification ? yarn run build in the component and relaunch yarn start in the app ? Thanks in advance,
Jon