# How to load a typings file as text with Webpack and React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-app-rewired

For setting up a Monaco editor instance I want to add a typings file for a custom lib. When mounting the editor I call:

```js
    public componentDidMount(): void {
        languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
            typings,
        );
    }
```

The variable `typings` is loaded by:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const typings = require("../../../modules/scripting/typings/my-runtime.d.ts");
```

Side note: the eslint comment is necessary or it will mark the `require` call as failure.

I use react-app-rewired to allow editing my webpack config without ejecting the CRA based application. Now the config-overrides.js file contains:

```js
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.plugins.push(new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
        languages: ["typescript", "javascript", "mysql", "json", "markdown"]
    }));

    config.module.rules.push(
        {
            test: /\.(html|d\.ts)$/i,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'raw-loader',
                    options: {
                        esModule: false,
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    );

    return config;
}
```

As you can see I actually handle 2 file types here: html and d.ts. The html part works nicely. A require call to load an .html file gives me the entire html file content (I need that to load an `<iframe>` with my custom runtime).

The require call for the typings file, however, returns an object (probably a module, hard to say as it appears empty in the debugger in vscode).

So the question is: how to change my config to make loading typings files (.d.ts) as text possible?

Comment: If you console.log typings , it prints your content?

Comment: are you using react-monaco-editor library to render dom?

Comment: @felixmosh All I get in the console is: `Object {}`.

Comment: @MuhammadNuman I use react-monaco-editor, yes.

Comment: @felixmosh When I change the extension to `.d-ts` then I get the path to the static web-packed file instead and can load that. So, I'm pretty sure some other loader kicks in before the raw-loader is used.

Comment: what is expecting output which you want?

Comment: are you want to show my-runtime.d.ts code in editor?

Comment: My question should pretty much explain it. I want to load the d.ts file as text to feed it to Monaco.

Comment: if you are not getting content outside of src then you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59986843/8079868

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you getting `{}`? I think because `babel-loader` loader rule (which handles `*.ts`) from `cra` conflicts with your `raw-loader` rule (which handles `*.d.ts`) and webpack decides to use `babel-loader` there.

I found two ways to handle this problem using `react-app-rewired`, please take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/nickbullock/monaco-cra-raw-import-example/blob/master/src/index.tsx).

1) Use `raw-loader` in a more aggressive inline way.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
const dogTypings = require('!!raw-loader?esModule=false!./dog.d.ts');
```

Explanation: `!!` meaning - disable all other rules in the configuration for this file. `import/no-webpack-loader-syntax` restricts to use inline syntax so we need to disable it there.

2) Remove ModuleScopePlugin from `cra` default config and create your typings outside of `src`.
By default you can't import anything from outside of `src`. But with `react-app-rewired` - of course you can. Here is config example:

```
const { resolve } = require('path');
const { removeModuleScopePlugin } = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    const newConfig = removeModuleScopePlugin()(config, env);

    newConfig.module.rules.push(
        {
            test: /\.(d\.ts)$/i,
            include: resolve(__dirname, 'typings'),
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'raw-loader',
                    options: {
                        esModule: false,
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    );

    return newConfig;
}
```

**Note**: both of these ways have a downside - they disable babel loader rule (which compiles typescript in `cra` apps actually) for these `.d.ts` files and type checking can be broken for their instances, but I did't check that. The problem with your code is the typescript compiler behavior, it removes `.d.ts` files from the runtime so webpack didn't emit them and I didn't found any way to prevent it.

Comment: I was about to write pretty much the same info for variant 1. The last missing piece to make this work was the `esModule=false` option. With that in place I got the entire content as text, just like I need it. Interesting to note here is also that suppressing the error about the webpack loader syntax did not work in .eslintrc. That has to happen in the source file.