# Why React - Create-React-Applications don't allow symlink?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

This might be a silly question to some, but I still don't understand why CRA - Create Reactive Applications does not allow symlink. This is a huge pain point. I am reading for the last hour about brave work arounds and magic quotes on Tweeter, but still don't understand why not? What does it try to protect so badly?

Comment: What's your mean? Why it's should appear in CRA? What's your purpose?

Comment: The scope is to allow symlink, that means sharing code between project without going through all the pain that Lerna adds in picture. Enable devs to do more rather than create obstacles and be opinionated...

Comment: if you don't know what I am referring to is this mitigation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory?rq=1  .... but here I am asking a different question. Is why is the limitation in place first.