# Can we call javascript function in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, onclick

I'm trying to convert the HTML template to react js. I have a js file where some functions are defined. Now when I tried to call that function in react js it shows me an error

> 'abc' is not defined  no-undef

Below is the function and details how I use to call it:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <li>
             <a href="#" onClick={abc('purple')} title="purple" className="color">link</a>
          </li>
    );
  }
}


function.js

abc(color){
alert(color);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `import` and `export` instead.

In `function.js`

```
export abc(color){
  alert(color);
}
```

In your React component file

```
import { abc } from './function.js'
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <li>
             <a href="#" onClick={()=>abc('purple')} title="purple" className="color">link</a>
          </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what if I've multiple functions? do I need to import all?

Comment: if you don't want to import the functions one by one, you can do like this: import * as myFunc from './function.js', and call the function by myFunc.abc() @JashanPabla

Comment: my function.js is in public folder and I'm not able to import it in src folder app.js file.I've include it in public/index.html via script tag

Comment: you can use ../ to travel to the upper directory @JashanPabla

Comment: Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. got this error

Comment: You can choose either move those functions inside the src folder (preferred) or follow this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44115058/10234091) to disable it. @JashanPabla