# How to reduce upward import with core-js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, core-js

I need to do import from a file that is in an another directive, so I go "up" with `import from '../../../Controls/example'`
I know that it can be reduced with core-js to something like `import from 'Controls/example'`, but I can't get how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean give a short alias name of local files?
You can add resolve.alias config in webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Controls: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../Controls/')
    }
  }
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

Comment: Thatnks for the answer! I followed your advice, but there's the mistake: Module not found: You attempted to import E:\Repo\pb.screen\pb\scr\ss\js\Controls/example which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: So, the file where I need do the import is located in: E:\Repo\pb.screen\pb\scr\ss\js\Views\MenuPage\Menu.js

Comment: if you are using creat-react-app, try to follow it's instruction, cause it has some custom config. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory/44115058

Comment: dunhuang, thanks a lot!! Your advice helped me, I added resole.alias in the wrong place the first time, but it works

Comment: glad that’s help