# Accessing public folder from CSS Module

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I'm currently building a project with React, and I'm using CSS modules for individual components.

In my public folder, I have `/images/Background.png`.
In App.module.css, I have the following;

```
.Container {
  background: url("./images/Background.png");
}
```

However, this throws the following error;

```
Can't resolve './images/Background.png' in 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Projects\Test\app\src\components\styles'
```

How should I access the contents of the public folder with a CSS Module?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your folder structure, but normally your `App.module.css` would be in the `src` while the `public` is outside of it, so the URL is wrong, try:

```
.Container {
    background: url("../public/images/Background.png");
}
```

If the file where you want to use it, not in the route level, you might need to go up a few levels.

When you do the above you will probably get the following error if your application was created with `create-react-app`:

> Module not found: You attempted to import
> ../public/images/Background.png which falls outside of the project
> src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

[Here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

Hope it helps, good luck.