# How to background-image css in React.Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

This is my tree folder

```
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── image.jpeg
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    ├── reportWebVitals.js
    └── setupTests.js
```

This is my **App.css**

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  background: url("/image.jpeg");
}
```

This is my **App.js**

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>asdasdasd</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm triying to add background-image to App.js but react throws this message

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css)
Error: Can't resolve '/image.jpeg' in '/home/ivan/Documents/code/REactJs/portafolio/src'
```

I'm dev on ubuntu 20, node version is v12.19.0

BTW I created this app yesterday and I dosen't work, but I have an old app I created a month ago and It works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think your `App.css` file can read images from your `public` folder, due to React's import restrictions from outside the `src` folder ([The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)). Instead, add an inline style to `App`

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundImage: "url('/image.jpeg')" }}>
      <h1>asdasdasd</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It worked but i want to know why i cant read images from public

Comment: This has to do with React's import restrictions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory

Answer (score 0):

I have faced issues with background image urls.

On the internet, I found 2 answers:

1. If the images are kept in `public` directory, use absolute path.
2. If the images are kept in `src` directory, use relative path.

I have observed that these answers did not work if the css file or style is in one or more level deeper from the src directory.

```
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── image.jpeg
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── a
    │   └── b
    │       ├── c.js
    │       └── c.css
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── images
    │   └── sample.png
    ├── logo.svg
    ├── reportWebVitals.js
    └── setupTests.js
```

The following would work, as `.logo` is kept in `src/index.css`:

```
.logo {
  background-image: url(images/sample.png)
}
```

But, the following will not, as the same is kept in `a/b/c.css`:

```
.logo {
  background-image: url(images/sample.png)
}
```

Finally, I learnt that, using absolute path works in all the scenarios. That is, the following works in all levels.

```
.logo {
  background-image: url(/images/sample.png)
}
```

The above also means that, using absolute path when the files are kept in `public` is not valid.

The whole thing is [here](https://github.com/tamilvendhank/react-background-image-url-issue-solution).

Further reference:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69615870/6999951
2. https://surajsharma.net/blog/background-image-in-react

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for image.jpeg in the wrong directory.
Your image.jpeg is found in /public, so try looking for it in `background: url("../public/image.jpeg");`
instead of `background: url("/image.jpeg");`

Comment: It Failed: ./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css)
Module not found: You attempted to import ../public/image.jpeg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The other answer works.