# Can't resolve '/images/img-2.jpg' in 'E:\React\react-demo\src'

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Here is my code i am trying to add image but its shows error

```
background-image: url('/images/img-2.jpg');
```

Failed to compile.

```
./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css)
Error: Can't resolve '/images/img-2.jpg' in 'E:\React\react-demo\src'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you asked for an image not founded in the `src` folder! maybe you're trying to access the images in the `public` folder at your React project.

My Friend's life is easy, **React - using Webpack - converts the jpg/png..etc images to base64** then replaces the URL to the base64... like this

[image]

So, you need to make an `assets/images` folder  inside the `src` folder that contains all your images, then import the link in your CSS

```
  background-image: url("./assets/images/logo512.png");
```

Again, React will convert the image to bases64! That will make the image not depend on the folder Path.

Comment: so all images should be moved to /assets/images from public. in html images from public is working..

Comment: Yes... Exactly!

Answer (score 4):

I got myself in a similar situation.
Here's the fix I made:
The error is saying that you do not have an **image**  under **src**

simply move the **image**  under **src** then redirect the URL to it

```
background: url('/src/images/img-2.jpg');
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/images/img-2.jpg']

Add your images to your src ... pretty much move it from `public` to the `src` folder

```
background-image: url('/src/images/img-2.jpg');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer could also be like below, 
background-image: url('@/assets/images/img-2.jpg'); // if your src folder is `assets`. i mean where you have kept your css, scss, images etc static folder.

So, you have to keep in mind that where is my static folder. Just add `@` icon then `/` and then the main source folder then then image path.

Answer (score 0):

*By setting the URL path to /image.png like the example above, the browser will look for the background image at /image.png.

You can also create another folder inside public/ if you want to organize your images into folders.*

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: "url(/image.png)}}>
  Hello World
</div>
```