# Module not found - project directory path error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, solidity, erc20

I am getting an error message that says: `Module not found: You attempted to import ../contracts/PreciousChickenToken.json which falls outside of the project src/ directory.` Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. How do i setup my relative path properly to consider the directory structure? i imported my contract .sol file into app.js like this: `import PreciousChickenToken from "./contracts/PreciousChickenToken.json";`

```
MyApp
  build/contracts
    PreciousChickenToken.sol
  client
    src
      app.js
```

Comment: Take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory).

Comment: @wgumenyuk hi thanks. yes, i already saw that but, I wanted to know specifically what I would need to type for my import line: ../contracts/PreciousChickenToken.json? I need something infront of ""../contracts".

Comment: maybe something like: "../../build/contracts/PreciousChickenToken.json"?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: thanks I got it to work