# Virtual directories with rootDirs - Typescript

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, tsconfig

I'm trying to fusion a folder outside my react project that contains some logic shared with another project using typescript [rootDirs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#virtual-directories-with-rootdirs)

I found that tsconfig.json gets reset after yarn start React app , so I made a `base-tsconfig.json` where I did put my config like this :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["src/datastore", "../Statsh.ReadModelBuilder/OnNewEvents/datastore"]
  }
}
```

and I updated the `tsconfig.json` to inherit from `base-tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./base-tsconfig.json"
}
```

But still getting compile fail :

[image]

How can I fix that issue ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)