# Can't render image from path in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I've saved images in an directory outside react project then I tried to render them in a react component but it fails.

[image: rendering]

[image: Project structure]

```html
// path: /frontend/src/components/Product.js
<img
    src='/uploads/image-1608360523657'
    style={{ width: 253, height: 208 }}
/>
```

Comment: check this ejecting solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58863926/5990249

Answer (score 0):

Import image like component :

```
import fallImg from "../uploads/image-1608360523657.jpg";
```

Comment: I can't do this because the uploads folder located outside react project folder because it's a static folder to the backend.

Comment: then u should bring the internet url from API or somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Import image first, then use specified name as a reference to the image

```
import someImageName from '/path/to/your/image/here'

<img
    src={someImageName}
    style={{ width: 253, height: 208 }}
/>
```

Comment: I can't do this because the uploads folder located outside react project folder because it's a static folder to the backend.