# Images not loading from Public folder (using create react app)

Tags: reactjs, image, create-react-app, public

wondering if anyone can help me. Im following a tutorial which has told me to put the images in the public folder in an app created with create-react-app

'./img/newyork.jpeg'

this is the path the tutorial told me to use for images in the public folder however the images aren't loading and i cant understand why any help would be much appreciated

[Build File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXj8E.png)

Comment: Have you put them to build?  It should be in public I guess

Comment: Did you copy your images to the build folder?

You run build only after you finished tested your code not before.

So if you did it won't find a thing unless you set the webpack to search for it over there which makes no sense at all.

A good practice is to add a folder named "assets" to your src folder and moving all the images / gifs / svgs etc... to there and not to the "public" folder.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't keep any image assets in the public folder other than favicons etc See this thread also: [The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory?rq=1) (TLDR: "This is special restriction added by developers of create-react-app. It is implemented in ModuleScopePlugin to ensure files reside in src/. That plugin ensures that relative imports from app's source directory don't reach outside of it.")

Generally in a create-react-app I would import images like so:

`import lovelyImage from 'images/lovely-image.jpg'`

and then rendered:

`<img src={lovelyImage} alt={''} />`

(the example above would assume the images directory is in the src directory (not public))

Answer (score 0):

process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'your image path'

is a solution I found that works