# cannot resolve relative url in scss react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I'm attempting to use a relative path within my **SCSS** to target an image file on my `public` directory (using native `create-react-app` environment):

```
.image{
    background: url("/cdn/static/images/logo/main_nav.png") center / contain;
}
```

Ideally, this would point to `localhost:3000/cdn/etc...` (where `cdn` is located in my `public` directory), however for some reason I just get an error in my **React** app:

> ./src/Imports/css/module/navigation.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/Imports/css/module/navigation.css)
>
> Error: Can't resolve '/cdn/static/images/logo/main_nav.png' in '/Users/user/Documents/react/app/src/Imports/css/module'

I'm unsure why **React** can't resolve the path, but it shouldn't even be looking in the first place. Should it not just be the stylesheet handling the retrieval?

Here's my file structure:

```
-app
  -public
    index.html
    -cdn
      -static
        -images
          -logo
            main_nav.png
  -src
    index.js
    -components
      -modules
        navigation.js (the file the css is imported into)
    -imports
      -css
        -module
          navigation.scss
          navigation.css (the generated css file)
```

All help is appreciated,
Cheers.

**EDIT**: If I try to use a relative url to the **React** app, I get this error:

> You attempted to import ../../../../public/cdn/static/images/logo/main_nav.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory

Comment: Try adding the path with respect to the compiled CSS file and not the SCSS file.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal they're both in the same folder

Comment: Try this `background: url("./cdn/static/images/logo/main_nav.png") center / contain;`

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal if I use `../../../../public/cdn/static/images/logo/main_nav.png` it says `You attempted to import { url } which falls outside of the project src/ directory`

Comment: Can you share your file structure?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal see edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)