# When call json file from i18n (outside of src folder) get error

Tags: json, directory-structure, i18next

When i call json file from i18n.js. get error msg  .Please someone can answer me what i wrong.
Thank you

[My folder structure of json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udWgz.png)

i18n.js

'''
import transitionEn from "../public/locales/translation/en-us.json";

import transitionJa from "../public/locales/translation/ja-jp.json";
'''

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The create-react-app imports restriction outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

Comment: place your translation files in public folder only if you’ll fetch them at runtime with i18next-http-backend: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb