# Importing a module outside of create-react-app src folder

Tags: reactjs

To begin, I've looked up various similar posts which have not solved my issue. I have tried using rescripts and other methods to no avail. I also am not able to move this file from it's original location.

I am in the process of building a create-react-app that utilizes an API for application data. The API file that I am using is named *api.js* and is outside of the src folder where my react application lives. When I try to import this module I receive an error saying,

**"Module not found: You attempted to import ../api which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported."**

Here is the folder structure that I am working with:

```
- react-jobly 
  - backend 
  - jobly
    - src 
      - Companies.js 
  - api.js
```

Comment: have you try using https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-link/?

Comment: Is the path correct ?

Comment: @Shyam Yes. I've changed the path and now I am receiving this error *'Module not found: You attempted to import ../api which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.'*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory