# running multiple react app and using common components from one folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a common folder outside the multiple react apps and pasted the common jsx component in them. but when I tried to access those common components in each of the react apps, I started to get an error saying that I couldn't import files outside the src/ directory of a react project.

***Project Structure***
Main Compomnent(folder)
React-app-1
React-app-2
React-app-3
React-app-4

I tried various paths and require, and **react-app-rewire** but couldn't get it to work.
I even tried some ways from [this site](https://betterprogramming.pub/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668) but no luck.

I tried to import the components as a dependency as well but it didn't work out.

so can any of you guys can help me out with this?
Appreciate the help :)

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory

Answer (score 1):

You can not access files that are not in the src folder.

You should create a separate repo for the common component. To access those components there are multiple ways -

1. You can clone that repo somewhere fixed path in every project and import with the path
2. Create common components as a different package with its own dependencies and use them with a symlink or with Lerna
3. you can publish the npm as private and add it in package.json.