# Image in public folder not loading after deployment

Tags: reactjs

I am using React to create my personal portfolio website.

I store images in the public folder and use them as `src='imageNames'`.

However, After I deployed the website using gitpage, the images no longer work in local development, though they work in production. They show a broken images instead. Any ideas? Thanks!

To Reproduce,

1.Create a boilerplate app and deploy the app to gitpage following https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

2.Replace `<img src='{logo}' className="App-logo" alt="logo" />` with `<img src='logo192.png' className="App-logo" alt="logo" />`

e.g.

```
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src='{logo}' className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Update: Importing images outside of the public folder work. I am wondering why public folder is not working anymore after deployment?

Comment: Hello, can you share your code ?

Comment: Added more detials @Monstar

Comment: What's the value of ``homepage`` in your ``package.json`` ?

Comment: is it working in your local system?

Comment: this might help maybe : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **create-react-app** it could be caused by the `homepage` value in your `package.json` being different than before you deployed:

```json
{
  "homepage": "http://yourUsername.github.io/yourProjectName"
}
```

If that's the case, this will change the default react directory to `/yourProjectName`.
So in your jsx you would need to add `/yourProjectName` by calling the following path instead:

```html
<img src="./yourProjectName/imageName.png" />
```

More information about relative paths in the docs [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths).

**Note**: You could then create an environment variable and call that instead for better reusability.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern to access images from the public folder.

```
 <img src={process.env.REACT_APP_FRONTEND_URL +'/assets/images/kid.png'}/>
```