# i have created a ABC folder of some components outside the src.Now i need to access that components inside src in react

Tags: reactjs

i have created one components folder which is outside the src .Now i need to access that components inside the src .
suggest steps to do that(instead of moving components folder inside src)And the other solutions didn't helped me to solve this

and the error is

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 27:0-198

Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../almLib/almLib 
which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative i 
imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from 
project's node_modules/.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this when using `Create React App`. There are some libraries that allow you to override this configuration but the best solution is to move your folder inside `/src`. If you still want to have this folder structure then you can follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory?rq=1) that includes many alternatives.

Comment: My requirement is to place that folder outside src only